# Wpf detect when notifypropertychanged has been fired

Tags: wpf, silverlight

I would like for my ui to perform some functions whenever the bound data has been modified.

Is it possible for the view to execute some code after the notifychange event has been called (due to changes in the underlying model)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your model implements INotifyPropertyChanged, you can subscibe to PropertyChanged event of it.

```
    model.PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(Model_PropertyChanged);

    void Model_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.PropertyName)
        {
        }
    }
```

and in the handler you can check which property is changed and do your work accordingly

Comment: Nice. My model is passed straight to the datacontext (not an mvvm project) but this should still apply?

Comment: sure.. you just need the instance of your the class to subscribe to its property change...